# "su" when the password is unknown but you're in "wheel" with "no password"

Tags: sudo, freebsd, users, password, root

I'm on FreeBsd 11. I have a user "user123" belonging to the group **wheel** and **wheel** has `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in `/usr/local/etc/sudoers`.

I don't know the password of root. However, I'm able to run "sudo" without one.

I've installed Postgresql and run it via "service start".

Now I want to log in as the postgresql user and create a database or other stuff:

```
$ su postgres
Password:


# or

$ su - postgres
Password:
```

But I don't know the password.

Is this the password of the user `root` or the user `postgres`? I don't know any of them. Is there a standard workaround for this?

Comment: I think your confusion is that you should be using `sudo` but you are actually using `su`. Different commands.

Comment: @roaima, I've tried to explain to him there's no connection between the `sudoers` file and the `su` command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to login as `postgres`, and you have `sudo` access without password requirements, do:

```
sudo -iu postgres
```

The `-i` starts a login shell.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat:  the question suggests you're using a personal server.  If not, and you aren't the main admin, do NOT assume root user's shell unless so instructed by the main admin**

---

### sudoers: 'wheel group' settings

`%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

So your *user123* user is in the 'wheel group' and your *sudoers* file grants unfettered access across `ALL` domains as `(ALL)` users with no password required for `ALL` commands, to members of the wheel group.

We know you have a working login so your options aren't limited.  Knowing the password for *postgres* or even *root*, isn't required.  You can simply:

`$ sudo -iu postgres`

---

### su, sudo, sudoers confusion

1. su  = substitute user
2. sudo = exec command as another user

The reason you can't 'substitute user' with `su` or `su -` as shown in the question is because the sudoers file has no effect on the `su` command.

The `su` command without arguments or just the dash defaults to *root*, so you get prompted for the root user password.  This is expected behaviour:  As the name *sudoers* implies, the sudoers file grants privilege to the `sudo` command only.

---

### root shell, lost password

As it appears you've forgotten the root password.  You can get the root shell using:

`$ sudo -i`

Leaving you back in control at: `[root@local ~]#`

Comment: `sudo su -` --> su: Sorry

Comment: @Dorion, `sudo su -` allows you to switch to the root user account using your own password.  If you try to `su -` or `su` instead (without the preceding `sudo`) you will need to know the actual root password.

Comment: you're the one who gave me 3 options and none of them worked.

Comment: @Dorion:  You should indeed be able to `sudo su`.

Comment: `sudo su` is an abomination. In this case `sudo passwd ...` would be sufficient.

Comment: This is the wrong solution to this user's problem. They don't need a root shell and resetting the system's root password isn't  going to get them closer to their goal (and even it it did, it would be a bad practice anyway). If they did just need a root shell `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` would be a better option, `sudo su` for any reason is a bad idea for several reasons. It may vary depending on your goals but there is always a way with less pitfalls than that.

Comment: Caleb is correct. To summarize: **Do not set the root password.** (Because not everyone reads paragraphs these days…)

Comment: @Caleb, Thanks for your input - I have taken it onboard and updated my answer. Based on the OP's question though, it seemed a reasonable assumption he's using a personal non-production server.  However I've updated my answer for future readers who might be in a production environment.   To be honest though, I can't imagine unfettered wheel access like that in a production environment, but anyway, it's fixed.

Comment: @Caleb the OP used the phrase "I don't know" re. passwords three times in the question body, and "password is unknown" in the question title. I think it was fair to include a password resetting solution given the substance of his question. Regardless, I have improved my answer with consideration to your input  and added a suitable caveat.

Comment: I'm sorry but as long as you're still suggesting doing exactly what we said was a bad idea you haven't "taken it onboard". Nobody should ever be  using `sudo su` for any reason, all it does is show that you don't understand the problem you're trying to solve and by using two tools that solve the same problem different ways you expose yourself to security issues you didn't  know were lurking there. Being a personal server is no excuse either, good practice in this case is no harder or more complicated than the bad practice. Pointing people to the bad practice is just bad practice.

Comment: @Caleb, Sorry I was conflating your comment with the other re. changing the root password.  I'm trying to address the OP's confusion about `su` re `sudo` and the  `sudoers` file, as nobody else has actually addressed this.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

```
$ sudo -i
# su - postgres
```

As *root*, you can use `su` without password. You can also combine these to

```
$ sudo su - postgres
```